# How do I test for even/odd page within TikZ \foreach loop

Tags: conditionals

I'm creating a document using the TikZ foreach loop.  Here's a snippet

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\foreach \myi in {1,2,...,17}
  {
    hello(\myi)
    \clearpage
    \ifoddpage
      A
    \else
      B
    \fi
  }

\end{document}
```

But this creates the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\pgffor@collectargument ...fter {\pgffor@body {#1}
                                                  }\else \expandafter \long ...
l.14   }
```

Any ideas of how to work around this?

Comment: Immediately after a \clearpage, \ifodd\value{page} will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ifoddpage` is not defined by default. You need to add that package to your preamble and also `\checkoddpage` before calling checking `\ifoddpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,ifoddpage}

\begin{document}

\foreach \myi in {1,2,...,17}{%
  \clearpage
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    A
  \else
    B
  \fi
  hello(\myi)
}

\end{document}
```

Here's the same approach using [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,refcount}

\newcounter{oddpagelabel}
\newcommand{\checkoddpage}{\stepcounter{oddpagelabel}\label{opl-\theoddpagelabel}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \myi in {1,2,...,17}{%
  \clearpage
  \checkoddpage
  \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{opl-\theoddpagelabel}
    A
  \else
    B
  \fi
  hello(\myi)
}

\end{document}
```